# Problema con submenú en php

Tags: php

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]Hola estoy teniendo problemas con este menú dinámico en php he logrado generar el menu con dos niveles de submenu pero el problema que se me presenta ahora es que necesito que el elemento que esté activo me lo muestre con el submenu abierto como la captura pero para lograr esto debo al  que esta afuera del foreach ponerlo de esta manera  pero como esta afuera del foreach del submenú no se como hacer esa lógica si alguien me ayuda porfa

```
<?php foreach($menu as $navegacion){ ?>
          <?php if($navegacion["mostrar_item_del_menu"] == "Sí") { ?>
            <li class="<?php if($navegacion["url"] == $page) { echo "active"; } ?>">
              <a class="sobre" href="<?php echo $navegacion["url"]; ?>"> <?php echo $navegacion["titulo"]; ?></a>
              <?php if($navegacion["activar_submenu"] == "Sí") { ?>
              <ul style="<?php if($trayendo["url"] == $page) { echo "display: block;"; } ?>">
              <?php } else { ?>
              <?php } ?>
              <?php foreach($submenu as $menu2) { ?>
              <?php if($navegacion["id_menu"] == $menu2["id_menu"]){ ?>
                  <?php if($menu2["mostrar_item_del_menu"] == "Sí") { ?>
                  <li class="<?php if($menu2["url"] == $page) { echo "active"; } ?>">
                    <a class="corriendo sobre" href="<?php echo $menu2["url"]; ?>"><?php echo $menu2["titulo"]; ?></a>
                     <?php if($menu2["activar_submenu"] == "Sí") { ?>
                     <ul>
                      <?php } else { ?>
                      <?php } ?>
                    <?php foreach($submenu2 as $menu3) { ?>
                      <?php if($menu3["id_submenu"] == $menu2["id_submenu"]){ ?>
                              <?php if($menu3["mostrar_item_del_menu"] == "Sí") { ?>
                              <li class="<?php if($menu3["url"] == $page) { echo "active"; } ?>">
                                <a class="corriendo2 sobre" href="<?php echo $menu3["url"]; ?>"><?php echo $menu3["titulo"]; ?></a>
                              </li>
                            <?php } else { ?>
                            <?php } ?>
                      <?php } else { ?>
                      <?php } ?>
                    <?php } ?>
                    <?php if($menu2["activar_submenu"] == "Sí") { ?>
                     </ul>
                      <?php } else { ?>
                      <?php } ?>
                  </li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <?php } ?>
              <?php } else{ ?>
              <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php if($navegacion["activar_submenu"] == "Sí") { ?>
                </ul>
                <?php } else { ?>
              <?php } ?>
            </li>
          <?php } else { ?>
          <?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: debo al <ul> que esta afuera del foreach ponerlo de esta manera <ul style="display: block;"> pero como esta afuera del foreach del submenú no se como hacer esa lógica si alguien me ayuda porfa

Comment: Resulta muy complicado leer tu código con tanta apertura y cierre de `<?php ... ?>`

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Answer (score 0):

Creo que puedes estar intentado hacer algo así:

```
<?php
// variables de navegación
$page='#';
$trayendo["url"]='#';
$menu=[
    [
        'mostrar_item_del_menu'=>'Sí',
        'url'=>'#',
        'titulo'=>'Primer link',
        'activar_submenu'=>'Sí',
        'id_menu'=>'1',
    ],
];
$submenu=[
    [
        'id_menu'=>'1',
        'mostrar_item_del_menu'=>'Sí',
        'url'=>'#',
        'titulo'=>'Primer link',
        'activar_submenu'=>'Sí',
        'id_submenu'=>'1',
    ],
];
$submenu2=[
    [
        'id_submenu'=>'1',
        'mostrar_item_del_menu'=>'Sí',
        'url'=>'#',
        'titulo'=>'Primer link',
        'activar_submenu'=>'Sí',
    ],
];
// código original
$txt=null;
foreach($menu as $navegacion){ 
    if($navegacion["mostrar_item_del_menu"] == "Sí"){ 
        $txt.='<li class="';
        if($navegacion["url"] == $page){
            $txt.='"active"';
        }
        $txt.='">';
        $txt.='<a class="sobre" href="';
        $txt.=$navegacion["url"]; 
        $txt.='">';
        $txt.=$navegacion["titulo"];
        $txt.='</a>';
        if($navegacion["activar_submenu"] == "Sí"){ 
            $txt.='<ul style="';
            if($trayendo["url"] == $page){
                $txt.='display: block;'; 
            }
            $txt.='">';
        }
        foreach($submenu as $menu2){ 
            if($navegacion["id_menu"] == $menu2["id_menu"]){ 
                if($menu2["mostrar_item_del_menu"] == "Sí"){ 
                    $txt.='<li class="';
                    if($menu2["url"] == $page){
                        $txt.='"active"'; 
                    }
                    $txt.='">';
                    $txt.='<a class="corriendo sobre" href="';
                    $txt.=$menu2["url"];
                    $txt.='">';
                    $txt.=$menu2["titulo"];
                    $txt.='</a>';
                    if($menu2["activar_submenu"] == "Sí"){ 
                        $txt.='<ul>';
                    } 
                    foreach($submenu2 as $menu3){ 
                        if($menu3["id_submenu"] == $menu2["id_submenu"]){
                            if($menu3["mostrar_item_del_menu"] == "Sí"){ 
                                $txt.='<li class="';
                                if($menu3["url"] == $page){
                                    $txt.='"active";';
                                } 
                                $txt.='">';
                                $txt.='<a class="corriendo2 sobre" href="';
                                $txt.=$menu3["url"];
                                $txt.='">';
                                $txt.=$menu3["titulo"];
                                $txt.='</a>';
                                $txt.='</li>';
                            } 
                            if($menu2["activar_submenu"] == "Sí"){ 
                                $txt.='</ul>';
                            }
                            $txt.='</li>';
                        } 
                    } 
                    if($navegacion["activar_submenu"] == "Sí"){ 
                        $txt.='</ul>';
                    } 
                    $txt.='</li>';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
echo $txt;
```

Varias cosillas:

- Aunque se pueda hacer en ambos sentidos, se suele meter el HTML en el PHP, no el PHP en el HTML. Como te han comentado, resulta más fácil de leer y localizar llaves sin cerrar y cosas así.
- Para poder depurar tu código, nos facilita mucho la tarea que nos pases el contexto: esos arrays con datos de prueba para comprobar el funcionamiento del código.
- Lo que necesitas, no termino de entenderlo, pero espero que, con el código algo más claro, veas tú mismo cómo hacerlo. Si necesitas algo más de ayuda, acláramelo un poco más en los comentarios o modifica tu pregunta ampliando los arrays de pruebas y mostrando qué pretendes hacer, qué opción no te funciona, etc